# Permanently delete files with custom upload folder in wordpress, wp-config

Tags: wordpress, image, upload

So i've noticed that when I moved my uploads folder somewhere else, wordpress no longer deletes the files I upload from that folder. It will delete it from inside Wordpress, but when i go to the folder, the files are still there.

I removed the custom path, reuploaded some files, and tried a "delete permanently" and it removed the files from the folder and from Wordpress. I switch the path again and it only deletes it from Wordpress; files still in custom folder.

Is there a way to have a custom path to the uploads folder and still be able to delete files permanently through Wordpress?

Thanks in advanced. 
WP 4.0

FYI, I've used this in my wpconfig

```
/** WordPress uploads directory. */
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'uploads' );
```

Comment: Does your folder in the new directory have the proper read/write permissions? Is it owned by the correct owner/group?

Comment: not 100% sure, but I am developing locally with WAMP. Again, WP can upload new files to the folder, but not delete them.